# How can I retrieve the email address from a Google Account and store it in my app's user profile when my user logs in using gae-simpleauth?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, user-permissions

I'm attempting to build a very simple user permissions system with webapp2's auth library. I'm using [gae-simpleauth](https://code.google.com/p/gae-simpleauth/) to log users in with their Google account. I'm hoping to compare the user's email address to a list of permitted email addresses to determine if a user has access to a resource, but I'm not clear on how to get the email address from the Google account into the account on my app. Users are currently able to log in, but the email address doesn't seem to be something simpleauth adds to their account by default.

How can I retrieve the email address from Google and store it in my app's user profile using gae-simpleauth?

My implementation of gae-simpleauth is nearly identical to the example with the addition of the `get_user_and_flags` function which fetches the logged in user and sets the admin flag if the user's email is in a list in secrets.py. Unfortunately, that doesn't work because user doesn't have an email attribute.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging, secrets, webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users
from webapp2_extras import auth, sessions, jinja2
from jinja2.runtime import TemplateNotFound
from lib.simpleauth import SimpleAuthHandler

def get_user_and_flags(self):
    """Returns the current user and permission flags for that user"""
    flags = {}
    user = None
    if self.logged_in:
        user = self.current_user
        flags = {
           'admin': user.email in secrets.ADMIN_USERS,
            }
    return user, flags

def simpleauth_login_required(handler_method):
    """A decorator to require that a user be logged in to access a handler.

    To use it, decorate your get() method like this:


        @simpleauth_login_required
        def get(self):
            user = self.current_user
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.name())
    """
    def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method != 'GET':
            self.abort(400, detail='The login_required decorator '
                                   'can only be used for GET requests.')

        if self.logged_in:
            handler_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.session['original_url'] = self.request.url.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
            self.redirect('/login/')

    return check_login

class BaseRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def dispatch(self):
    # Get a session store for this request.
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

    try:
      # Dispatch the request.
      webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
      # Save all sessions.
      self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

  @webapp2.cached_property    
  def jinja2(self):
    """Returns a Jinja2 renderer cached in the app registry"""
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def session(self):
    """Returns a session using the default cookie key"""
    return self.session_store.get_session()

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def auth(self):
      return auth.get_auth()

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def current_user(self):
    """Returns currently logged in user"""
    user_dict = self.auth.get_user_by_session()
    return self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_id(user_dict['user_id'])

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def logged_in(self):
    """Returns true if a user is currently logged in, false otherwise"""
    return self.auth.get_user_by_session() is not None


  def render(self, template_name, template_vars={}):
    # Preset values for the template
    values = {
      'url_for': self.uri_for,
      'logged_in': self.logged_in,
      'flashes': self.session.get_flashes()
    }

    # Add manually supplied template values
    values.update(template_vars)

    # read the template or 404.html
    try:
      self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(template_name, **values))
    except TemplateNotFound:
      self.abort(404)

  def head(self, *args):
    """Head is used by Twitter. If not there the tweet button shows 0"""
    pass


class ProfileHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    """Handles GET /profile"""    
    if self.logged_in:
      self.render('profile.html', {
        'user': self.current_user, 
        'session': self.auth.get_user_by_session()
      })
    else:
      self.redirect('/')


class AuthHandler(BaseRequestHandler, SimpleAuthHandler):
  """Authentication handler for OAuth 2.0, 1.0(a) and OpenID."""

  # Enable optional OAuth 2.0 CSRF guard
  OAUTH2_CSRF_STATE = True

  USER_ATTRS = {
    'facebook' : {
      'id'     : lambda id: ('avatar_url', 
        'http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=large'.format(id)),
      'name'   : 'name',
      'link'   : 'link'
    },
    'google'   : {
      'picture': 'avatar_url',
      'name'   : 'name',
      'link'   : 'link'
    },
    'windows_live': {
      'avatar_url': 'avatar_url',
      'name'      : 'name',
      'link'      : 'link'
    },
    'twitter'  : {
      'profile_image_url': 'avatar_url',
      'screen_name'      : 'name',
      'link'             : 'link'
    },
    'linkedin' : {
      'picture-url'       : 'avatar_url',
      'first-name'        : 'name',
      'public-profile-url': 'link'
    },
    'foursquare'   : {
      'photo'    : lambda photo: ('avatar_url', photo.get('prefix') + '100x100' + photo.get('suffix')),
      'firstName': 'firstName',
      'lastName' : 'lastName',
      'contact'  : lambda contact: ('email',contact.get('email')),
      'id'       : lambda id: ('link', 'http://foursquare.com/user/{0}'.format(id))
    },
    'openid'   : {
      'id'      : lambda id: ('avatar_url', '/img/missing-avatar.png'),
      'nickname': 'name',
      'email'   : 'link'
    }
  }

  def _on_signin(self, data, auth_info, provider):
    """Callback whenever a new or existing user is logging in.
     data is a user info dictionary.
     auth_info contains access token or oauth token and secret.
    """
    auth_id = '%s:%s' % (provider, data['id'])
    logging.info('Looking for a user with id %s', auth_id)

    user = self.auth.store.user_model.get_by_auth_id(auth_id)
    _attrs = self._to_user_model_attrs(data, self.USER_ATTRS[provider])

    if user:
      logging.info('Found existing user to log in')
      # Existing users might've changed their profile data so we update our
      # local model anyway. This might result in quite inefficient usage
      # of the Datastore, but we do this anyway for demo purposes.
      #
      # In a real app you could compare _attrs with user's properties fetched
      # from the datastore and update local user in case something's changed.
      user.populate(**_attrs)
      user.put()
      self.auth.set_session(
        self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))

    else:
      # check whether there's a user currently logged in
      # then, create a new user if nobody's signed in, 
      # otherwise add this auth_id to currently logged in user.

      if self.logged_in:
        logging.info('Updating currently logged in user')

        u = self.current_user
        u.populate(**_attrs)
        # The following will also do u.put(). Though, in a real app
        # you might want to check the result, which is
        # (boolean, info) tuple where boolean == True indicates success
        # See webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User for details.
        u.add_auth_id(auth_id)

      else:
        logging.info('Creating a brand new user')
        ok, user = self.auth.store.user_model.create_user(auth_id, **_attrs)
        if ok:
          self.auth.set_session(self.auth.store.user_to_dict(user))

    # Remember auth data during redirect, just for this demo. You wouldn't
    # normally do this.
    self.session.add_flash(data, 'data - from _on_signin(...)')
    self.session.add_flash(auth_info, 'auth_info - from _on_signin(...)')

    # Go to the last page viewed
    target = str(self.session['original_url'])
    self.redirect(target)

  def logout(self):
    self.auth.unset_session()
    self.redirect('/')

  def handle_exception(self, exception, debug):
    logging.error(exception)
    self.render('error.html', {'exception': exception})

  def _callback_uri_for(self, provider):
    return self.uri_for('auth_callback', provider=provider, _full=True)

  def _get_consumer_info_for(self, provider):
    """Returns a tuple (key, secret) for auth init requests."""
    return secrets.AUTH_CONFIG[provider]

  def _to_user_model_attrs(self, data, attrs_map):
    """Get the needed information from the provider dataset."""
    user_attrs = {}
    for k, v in attrs_map.iteritems():
      attr = (v, data.get(k)) if isinstance(v, str) else v(data.get(k))
      user_attrs.setdefault(*attr)

    return user_attrs
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this help( I have same probblem )

First change in `secrets.py` in line:

```
'google': (GOOGLE_APP_ID, GOOGLE_APP_SECRET, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'),
```

to

```
'google': (GOOGLE_APP_ID,GOOGLE_APP_SECRET, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'),
```

and in `auth.py` change USER_ATTRS =

```
{
 ...
 'google'   : {
      'picture': 'avatar_url',
      'email'   : 'email', <-- new attr
      'name'   : 'name',
      'link'   : 'link'
    },
}
```

Comment: This looks really promising. Thank you for posting it. I'm trying it out now.

Comment: I've implemented this just as you suggested, but I'm still coming up against the same error. Just to confirm, I should add the additional URL to the same string with a space between, correct?

Comment: When my app comes to this line of code `'admin': user.email in secrets.ADMIN_USERS` I get this error: `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'email'`

Comment: Not sure what you got, I have modify example of simpauth at `https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwOnfUDw6AIoNlpWSVJDcEpzTTg/edit?usp=sharing`. It run ok in my localhost

Answer (score 1):

Since your question includes no code snippet, I can only guess at what you have done so far. In light of that, the below code should work:

```
from google.appengine.api import users

user = users.get_current_user()

email = user.email()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `user.get_current_user()` is returning `None` even though I'm logged in. It seems as though simpleauth maybe doesn't talk to the App Engine Users API.

Comment: I added my implementation of simpleauth to my original post. Is this what you need? I'm not sure that it will help answer my question. I didn't think I would need to post my code since I only need to know how to have simpleauth add the email address to my user profile. I figured I could use a generic implementation of this. I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea of nguyên, I add customize also the "_to_user_model_attrs" method.
Here my piece of code:

```
    def _to_user_model_attrs(self, data, attrs_map):
    """Get the needed information from the provider dataset."""

    user_attrs = {}
    for k, v in attrs_map.iteritems():

        if v =="email":
            attr = (v, data.get(k)[0].get('value'))
        else:
            attr = (v, data.get(k)) if isinstance(v, str) else v(data.get(k))
        user_attrs.setdefault(*attr)

    return user_attrs
```

It works for me!

Answer (score -1):

There seem to be several methods of authentication, and mix-matching does not work. If you havne't already, make sure you read through this, https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

There are a few sections that might be relative depending on what else you have been doing with Google.

Changes from the Google Apps account transition

Configuring Google Apps to Authenticate on Appspot